# The REPL of sublime text 2 can't using the command of git?

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I installed REPL in sublime text 2, and I want to use git on REPL, but it didn't work, and note that 'git' is not an command, but git work in cmd well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SublimeREPL is for programming language interpreters like Clojure or Python, not shell programs like `git`. What you need is [`sublime-text-2-git`](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-git/wiki), available from the [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) menu as "Git". [`SideBarGit`](https://github.com/SublimeText/SideBarGit) may also be useful.